# routes redirect me to home page ( laravel )

Tags: apache, nginx, laravel-4, ubuntu-14.04

ok
now i installed laravel 4.2 on ubuntu 14.4 with apache and nginx proxy .

and when i create route like

```
Route::get('/reg', function()
{
    return 'hii';
});
```

apache view "hii" when i call "localhost:8080/reg"

but nginx view main page when i call "localhost/reg" in browser

the nginx config :

```
server {
        listen   80;

        root /var/www/laravel/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

        location ~ \.php$ {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

         }

 # PHP FPM configuration.
    location ~* \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index                   index.php;
            fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script$
    }

         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

where is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your `nginx.conf`, It's loading your `/var/www/laravel/public/index.php;`. If you don't want that to happen,

- adjust the path in `nginx.conf` to the file you want to `load`,

`OR`

- make a view, and then point the path to that view.